# No option for Android 13 AOSP for Pixel 4a emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

## Problem

I try to create a virtual Pixel 4a device with Android 13 and no Google APIs (I guess that means just the base AOSP version).

In my `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2` there is no option to choose such a system image for a Pixel 4a:

[image: System Image Chooser]

Under the recommended section there is one, but it comes with Google APIs.

## Question

How can I get a de-googled AVD for a Pixel 4a with the newest Android 13?